# writing oval validations in xml

Tags: xml, oval

I'm trying to write the equivalent of the below java Assert statement in OVAL XML configuration file in the MVEL expression language. But I'm unable to do so. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class BusinessObject 
{
   // mailingAddress must either be the delivery address or the invoice address 
   @Assert(expr = "_value ==_this.deliveryAddress || _value ==  this.invoiceAddress", lang = "groovy")

   public String mailingAddress;
}
```

The xml..

```
<class type="BusinessObject" applyFieldConstraintsToSetters="true" overwrite="false">
    <field name="mailingAddress">
        <assert lang="mvel" expr="_value ==_this.deliveryAddress || _value ==  this.invoiceAddress" message="mailingAddress must either be the delivery address or the invoice address ">
        </assert>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<class type="BusinessObject" applyFieldConstraintsToSetters="true" overwrite="false">
   <field name="mailingAddress">
       <assert lang="mvel" message="mailingAddress must either be the delivery address or the invoice address">
           <expr>_value ==_this.deliveryAddress || _value ==  this.invoiceAddress</expr>
       </assert>
   </field>
</class>
```

Also see https://sourceforge.net/p/oval/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/test/resources/net/sf/oval/test/validator/XMLConfigurationTest.xml